# this function will return True if all words in worddict is present in string . Word break problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, dynamic-programming

```
def word_break(s,worddict):
    dp =[False] * (len(s) +1)
    dp[0] = True
    f = len(s)
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for word in worddict:
            k = len(worddict)
            if (len(word))<= len(s) and s[i:i+len(word)] == word:
               t = f-k
               dp[t] = True
               k-=1

    return dp[len(s)]

word_dict =['leet','code']
s = 'codeleet'
brk = word_break(s,word_dict)
print(brk)
```

I calculated the value of k to place true in such a way that I got answer at the last element of dp array.

My logic is not working as expected.

I am trying to put result in dp array after processing a word in such a way the last word result get placed on the last element of dp.

Comment: It's absolutely not obvious what you want to do here? `t = f-k` is always the same (given `s` and `worddict`), so - wild guess - do you actually want `k = len(word)`?

Comment: Run through your code with a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to try to understand how your code works so that you can modify it to suit your requirements.

Comment: yes , i reduce the value of k by 1 after a word is processed , k-=1 . so in this case k is not always remain the same . lets assume we have 2 words in worddcit if one word matches then t = 8-2  = 6 , so dp[6] = True , k-=1 , now k  = 1 , if second word matches then t = 8-1 = 7 , so dp[7] = True (this is the last position) and im expecting getting answer at last position

Comment: No, you don't: You set `for word in worddict: k = len(worddict)` in _each_ loop! `k -= 1` doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure is that's what you expected but if you want to place True at the last element of the list you just need to delete your operation

```
t = f - k
```

because f is the len of the table and k is equal 2 so you place your True at the position dp[-3]
for the last element True you need to do :

```
dp[f] = True
```